# Why is their lag in my css injecting chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

I recently created a chrome extension which injects a css file into Facebook. However, now my Facebook lags and freezes when scrolling.

Here is some more info. The extension runs a content script which injects the file via jquery before the page is loaded. Using "run_at": "document_start" ensures it's injected before the page is loaded and I have verified this through the inspector. The changes are apparent so I know the file is being loaded correctly. The css file is short and I place !important after every statement to ensure they are not overridden.

I thought that since I am only adding a stylesheet, the page would operate as smoothly as normal. However, there is considerable lag when scrolling to new content. Once I have scrolled past new content, I can scroll back up or back down again past the content with no lag. Any ideas? I can post any code that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject CSS directly with [tabs.insertCSS](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS) programmatically or [via the manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration), so you generally don't need to do it with a content script unless you somehow adapt the CSS on the fly. Does this help with the issue?